# Strategy for storing files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am currently working on a e-commerce application for practice purposes , more precisely a file storage component to simplify my work.I am planing on using it for future projects.

This is basically how everything will work.

In my database I will have two tables that will be related to files.

The Files table will store the file OrigineFileName and StorageFileName (unique name).

Each file will have a file type which will be stored in the Filetypes table.Here I will have a partial file path witch will look something like this: Products{0}\Avatar.

{0} will be replaced in my component with a unique number most likely it will be the product id.

I posted a diagram with the two tables for better understanding:

[image]

The only problem that I have left is how do I set the first part of my url witch also contains the drive letter.

At the moment my only idea is to set the first part of the url in the appsetings of web config and retrieve it with the ConfigurationManager class.

I am not really sure if this is a good idea because when I will post the application on the server the path will surely change and everytime I will update the web application I will have to update the web.config.

Comment: Why not use a VirtualFileSystem with an external config file and store in your DB urls like "~/files/filename.xxx".

Comment: hmm...I do not know what that is can you provided so link with some documentation?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/sharpfilesystem/). It's just one maybe you can find other better for your needs.

Comment: Maybe you want to store your files on a drive but know that SQL Server handles BLOB (Binary Large Objects) storage: [Binary Large Object (Blob) Data (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx) and [Compare Options for Storing Blobs (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403405.aspx)